# Data structure and algorithms for a medical diagnosis software

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

For an academic question, I plan to design a medical diagnosis system. Given a description of symptoms, produce a list of probable diseases (with closeness matching). I'm having some trouble finding papers for getting started. Which algorithms and data structure should I consider?

Answer (score 3):

Machine learning algorithms and techniques are very successful and best practice in this area (clustering and classification techniques could be uses). For example in [Machine Learning Techniques for AD/MCI Diagnosis and Prognosis](http://www.unc.edu/~ptyap/papers/Machine_Learning_in_Healthcare%20Informatics_Wee_Machine%20Learning_Techniques_for_AD_MCI_Diagnosis_and_Prognosis.pdf) or [Medical decision support systems based on machine learning](http://ir.uiowa.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1469&context=etd), thesis written by Chih-Lin Chi.

You can use simple records in database as the data model.

Answer (score 3):

The field of probabilistic graphical models is often used for medical diagnosis, and some tools have been implemented. See [this example](http://www.ifw-kiel.de/ifw_portal/konfer/esf-ifw/newtech06/diez_luque.pdf), for a start.

Also see [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1560518/).